# Converting Json.Net JValue to int

Tags: c#, json.net

I've tried:

```
JValue myJValue = getJValue(someVar);
int storedValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJValue);
```

But this only seems to be valid for JObjects. Is there a way to get the integer from a JValue?

Comment: `DeserializeObject` only takes a string parameter...

Comment: Good point, got muddled there

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Maybe this helps you along:

```
int storedValue = myJValue.ToObject<int>();
```

Answer (score 21):

For anyone interested in Performance, `Value()` is much much quicker than `ToObject()`. For strings, just use `ToString()`

Int Test:

```
value.Value<int>() - 2496ms
value.ToObject<int>() - 6259ms
```

Double Test:

```
value.Value<double>() - 572ms
value.ToObject<double>() - 6319ms
```

String Test:

```
value.Value<string>() - 1767ms
value.ToObject<string>() - 6768ms
value.ToString() - 130ms
```

.

```
    private static void RunPerfTest()
    {
        int loops = 100000000;
        JValue value = new JValue(1000d);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            double x = value.Value<double>();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("value.Value<double>()" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            double x = value.ToObject<double>();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("value.ToObject<double>()" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

int storedValue = (int)myJValue;

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers here already but I want to add one more that people may find useful.  If you have a `List<JValue>`, let's call it `myJValueList` and the `JValue` objects in the list are internally holding an `int` then you can get that `int` doing the following:

```
foreach(int myInt in myJValueList){
    //do some work with the myInt 
}
```